# where is the default sqoop hive import destination directory? is it controllable?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I need to do a sqoop import all tables from an existing mysql database to hive, the first table is categories.

The command is as below:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 1 \
--connect=jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com/retail_db \
--username=retail_user \
--password=itversity \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--create-hive-table \
--compress \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
--outdir java_output0322
```

It failed for the following reason:

> Output directory
>   hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/paslechoix/categories already
>   exists

I am wondering how can I import them into `/apps/hive/warehouse/paslechoix.db/`

paslechoix is the hive database name.

**UPDATE1 on 20180323 to Bala who commented at the first place:**

I've updated the script to:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 1 \
--connect=jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com/retail_db \
--username=retail_user \
--password=itversity \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-database paslechoix_new \
--compress \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
--outdir java_output0323
```

added what you suggested: --hive-database paslechoix_new 
paslechoix_new is a new hive database just created.

I still receive error of:

> AlreadyExistsException: Output directory
>   hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/paslechoix/categories already
>   exists

Now, it is really interesting, why it keeps referring to **paslechoix**? I already indicate in the script that the hive database is **paslechoix_new**, why it doesn't get recognized?

**Update 2 on 20180323:**

I took the other suggestion in Bala's comment:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 1 \
--connect=jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com/retail_db \
--username=retail_user \
--password=itversity \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-database paslechoix_new \
--warehouse-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/paslechoix_new.db \
--compress \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
--outdir java_output0323
```

So now the import doesn't throw error any more, however, I checked the hive database, all the tables are created, **with no data**

Answer (score 0):

add the option `--warehouse-dir` to import into a specific directory

```
--warehouse-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/paslechoix.db/
```

if you want to import to specific hive database, then use

```
--hive-database paslechoix
```

Comment: at least the second option is not working, I've updated in the OP